# The property identifier in OpenCV only gives even-numbered frames

Tags: python, opencv

I have a strange problem. I have a video in Python 2.7.9, called `vid`, and I'm using `vid.get(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)` to get the frame numbers in order to loop through the frames. If I get the first frame, I want to change the value of a flag. But it doesn't detect the first frame.

```
# mark the first frame
if vid.get(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) == 1:
   print "Found the first frame"
```

I printed out `vid.get(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)` and the result is:

```
0.0
2.0
4.0
6.0
8.0
```

So I put the condition to be frame 2, and it gave me:

```
0.0
2.0
Found the first frame
4.0
6.0
8.0
```

Why is this happening?

Here's an MCVE:

```
vid = cv.VideoCapture('C:\users\username\bouncingBall.avi')
totalFrames = vid.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
while vid.get(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) < totalFrames - 1:
    print vid.get(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
    # mark the first frame
    if vid.get(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) == 1:
        print "Found the first frame"
        first_frame = True
    else:
        first_frame = False
```

Comment: can you post an mcve?

Comment: You mean the video I'm using?

Comment: Added it. See my edit.

Comment: where did you actually grab the frame?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. What do you mean, where?